# Python Socket Programming - broadcasting to one client

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I'm making a serverside chat (in Python of course) and it uses this function to broadcast to all clients:

```
def broadcast_data (sock, message):
    for socket in CONNECTION_LIST:
        if socket != server_socket and socket != sock:            
            socket.send(message)
```

I'm curious how can I send a message only to one client. I did some research but everyone is broadcasting the message to all. If anyone has a good source to learn it from or if anyone can tell me how it is done, I would be thankful.

Comment: "Broadcasting" to a single client is easy: Just `socket.send(...)`. That's it. No loop, just get the socket you want to send the message to, and send it. And sending only to a single (or a few) connections is not really a *broad*cast.

Comment: Oh so I guess I should connect the socket list with my username list to specify the client's socket right?

Comment: Well you could have a class to hold both the user-data and the socket, and for each connection you create an object of that class that you put in a list. But yes what you say is one way to do it.

Comment: Great thanks! And if I use the "socket.send(message)" where do I specify the target socket?

Comment: You need a pair of server - client. Server should bind and listen on port and client should connect (to ip) and send (data). [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html?highlight=socket#module-socket) [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm) .

Comment: I know, I have server and client already but I don't know how to specify the target client ( when using socket.send() ) when I have more on them on the server.